# Sorting date ranges against array instances (recursion)

Tags: javascript, recursion, multidimensional-array, schedule

If I had to sort date ranges objects or arrays into multiple instances of arrays so that the ranges don't conflict (constructing a schedule,) I could just iterate over every single one populating it with ranges until the very biggest non-conflicting end range is pushed into an instance, but wouldn't it be simpler to not iterate over an instance of "room"/array, but date ranges?

This function would loop for amount of rooms and determining overall availability, but it's intensive, and I'd rather see something that iterates over data (provided I put initial constraints on data to not require more instances of rooms than physical actuals).

```
function fillScheduleForRoom(n) {
 if Math.max(n.end) < Math.min(data.start) 
   // sort data by ascending order, but should I call each on Math.min?
   data = Math.min(data.index).splice //
   return function fillScheduleForRoom(n.push[Math.min(data)])
 if else Math.min(n.end) = unidentified
   return function fillScheduleForRoom([[null],[null]]);
 else return n;
}
```

P.S. I realize that I'd have to store data[min] into another variable to splice and return function (push var forDataMin).

Notice: Application usage for this being unorthodox method of creating a booking app where from this function you make an array representing availability and in my case insert the new array without owner. Showing unowned array indexes (reservation spots) to clients to update as their own and with their date ranges running this function again after that. In order to create constraints on startup run another function iterating over rooms creating reservation spots for amount and/or types of space.

Elaboration: goes as something like this: there's reservation json with title matching a room type (penthouse) and a dates of stay along with user to whom it belongs. One of these puppies is ingested along with others into a sworm where they all begin filling up the room on a timeline, to then procede to the next one as fillScheduleForRoom is looped over room amount (pretty much config). The way that function is meant to work is that it takes the next closest reservation to previously made and sticks it after the reservation already placed- into array (rather than .min of data start of stay). This way you basically wind up populating the first room as much as possible while leaving last room hypothetically free, at which point if you take the gaps and insert those as new reservations that you let users update as their own, point at which you take an unowned reservation that spans the entirety of schedule that means that when running the function that's data centric rather than looping over room amounts you'd have to be creating a new instance of that room as previous instances don't fit that reservation in their schedules. Once reservation for a room ends, it's successor that has dates starting after end of previous start and ending in true or infinity (hopefully true does it) takes over for a user to update as own, triggering this function again creating new reservations (by taking start and end dates of 2 reservation, and if that fails just appending true).

I work on meteor.js which doesn't require ajax, or dealing with callbalcks while also being isomorphic, so that's the simpler solution the way I see it to writing out logic that concludes that a query into making reservation is acceptable.

Comment: Solutions to [scheduling problems such as this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurse_scheduling_problem#Solutions) are not trivial. If your problem is small enough to be brute-forced, and you get it working, you should leave it at that. If not, we need an exact description of your hard and soft constraints; otherwise a good answer is very hard.

Comment: BTW, your code is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: Updated the question, reading the article linked.

Comment: @trincot I'm a beginner, and would appreciate any edit suggests (had diffiuclty articulating looping functions over room types and amounts to create 2d array nesting reservations and their times).

Comment: @bergi I suppose what you're looking for is that if a new room amount or type is created I just compare for how parameters have changed creating a new reservation spot(s) if there's an increase and in decrease have a condition that also returns what the last room(s) look like in case of decrease in amount or type while disregarding those results for (n).

Comment: I cannot make head or tails of your code. Could you provide sample data, with an example call and expected outcome, with concrete figures?

Comment: @trincot updated to include how it's both suppose to look instead of what I wrote, and how it works.

Comment: I see no answer to my questions. Probably my English skills are not good enough, but I can't understand what you are saying. I am moving on. Maybe someone else can help you.

Comment: The way that I see the answer go is that you actually put the loop for rooms inside the function for data unshifting/poping it at the end of a run if it's already ordered breaking it once it fits and placing it there, but that still would be as intense as you can't just approximate this solution to something that doesn't write and read as much by using logic when it needs to update. @bergi any chance that this is what I actually use as apposed to what I have up there thinking I'm lacking a better word than min(data.start).